# Cloudformation for URLHealthcheck with SNS Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to define a Route53 URL Healthcheck with an alarm referring to an existing SNS Topic.

I'm unable to find how to define this Alarm within the Route53 URL Health Check CF template:

My Cloudformation URLHealthCheck template:

```
 ASDDURLHealthCheck: 
    Type: "AWS::Route53::HealthCheck"
    Properties: 
      HealthCheckConfig:
        FullyQualifiedDomainName: "newserver.aws.lilly.com"
        Port: "8888"
        Type: "HTTPS"
        ResourcePath: "/new"
        RequestInterval: "30"
        FailureThreshold: "3"
```

I want to add SNS Alarm to the above in the following way:

```
    AlarmActions: 
        -   "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:xxxxxxx:MySNSTopic"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm" resource.

```
HealthCheckStatusAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmDescription: HealthCheckStatus
    AlarmActions:
    - arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:xxxxxxx:MySNSTopic
    MetricName: HealthCheckStatus
    Namespace: AWS/Route53
    Statistic: Minimum
    Period: '60'
    EvaluationPeriods: '3'
    Threshold: '1'
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
    Dimensions:
    - Name: HealthCheckId
      Value:
        Ref: ASDDURLHealthCheck
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudwatch.html#cloudwatch-sample-cpu-utilization-alarm